# Should a confirmation-before-submitting page on a form contain all the information a user has entered?

Tags: forms

I'm working on a product with a long, single-page form.

This form contains between 18 and 32 (these numbers may change in the future) fields -- this number depends on the version of the form the user selects.

A feature we are building is a page after the user fills out this form and presses "continue", to have the user review the details they entered on the previous page to make sure that information is accurate before they submit.

Previously, this page only showed key pieces of information. However, I'm considering showing all of the information that the user entered on the previous screen instead.

**Does it seem weird to only show parts of the form's details?**

**Additionally, is it too repetitive to show all the fields a user recently input on the very next page?**

Comment: Is every piece of information in this form equally important and in need of confirmation? 18-32 is a lot of fields to confirm, whether immediately after the page or in the usual location at the end, before finishing the process. You might consider only showing crucial information for confirmation, or designing the form interactions to minimize the chance for mistakes.

Comment: For each field: why are we asking this? Who will use this? What will they use it for?

Answer (score 1):

I would be frustrated if only *some* of the data were there to be reviewed. A nagging feeling would follow me away that there was something *else* there, and I might go back specifically to review the information that was not originally shown.

As long as the format is compact, it does not seem to be too much to display all of the data

Answer (score 1):

If the last step that is bing done by the user is entering those details only, you can also confirm those points at that place only; as part of the form design. Taking 18-32 fields and asking the user to verify them in one click, will directly **increase the mental load** of the user. In this case the screen might lead to slips, as **verifying too many data points in one click will increase the probability of mistake**.

You should try designing the form fields in such a way, where user is aware of each and every data point and the action is, his/her conscious call, not a mistake. For example, in case of profile related data , you can give visual feedback in the same time, while entering the data.(P.S. : I'm not aware of the type of content you are dealing with, assuming general practices, I'm suggesting)

Answering another question regarding weirdness of partial information, IMO it might lead to anxiety as well and I also feel the same as the first statement of @Academiphile.

Answer (score 0):

When there's a confirmation screen and you need to have user validate the data he entered, I'd vote for you to have all the information there or no information and skip confirmation altogether.

Yes, you could try a better arrangement on the confirmation screen to outline what's most important but if I gave you some information as a user let me either see it all or not at all. Yes, there's a risk of feeling a bit overwhelmed but at the same time, you won't want to give me the feeling you asked me for loads of information while you truly needed just a little bit of it isn't it?